# How to obtain handle to notification window in Windows 10

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, winapi

I would like to obtain handle to notification window (balloon) using WinAPI. How can I do it, correctly?

Currently I found the solution by enumerating all windows using **FindWindowEx** function and then obtaining all windows that belongs to **ShellExperienceHost.exe** process. The operation is executed using **GetWindowThreadProcessId** API call.

After that we are limited to five windows and one of that window is notification window. But, the only parameter I can base on is window name. In this certain case it is "New notification". However, for my native language it is "Nowe powiadomienie". The application I am currently working on, needs to support multiple language. So, creating set with the names is not good options. Because, the code will be difficult to maintenance and can be depend on further changes in Windows.

I will be grateful for any help in this area.

Comment: Use this API: ``GetGUIThreadInfo``: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: x-y ... Why would you ever need that handle?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Currently I am working on screen sharing technology and I need to hide the content of that Window while sending the desktop content to other users. This is potential security issue, because we are leaking sensitive data such as private messages etc.

Comment: You could try [UI automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx), it might give you a way to find the window without relying on localized strings. Use the Inspect tool to check which information you get using UI automation.

Comment: "*the only parameter I can base on is window name*" - did you try looking at the window **class name** yet?

Comment: This is not the only place where information may leaks. I think you are chasing a ghost here. Once the user shares the screen then they are making an explicit decision to let somebody else see what appears there. You can't win this battle.

Comment: @zett42 I used **Spy++** tool to investigate the window hierarchy.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The notification window has **Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow** type. What is quite common in the window hierarchy and it can not be used as a a point of attachment. Moreover we can not base on the **Z** axis, because the window has got **TOPMOST** style. Moreover, the overall window style is not different than other windows.

Comment: @David Hefferman we let user to share his/her application window. We do not want to leak any other unrelated applications. We do it quite well for UWP and regular window application, but in this certain scenario we don't have good solution.

Comment: OK, application sharing is different from screen sharing. So why don't you do that? Why are you sending anything other than the application window? You can capture that and nothing else. Trying to pick on one specific class of notification window is futile. What about other popup windows that aren't of this class? So your current approach is doomed to fail.